# If the value between the bars starts with ONE letter followed by several numbers, no more letters, then replace with a specific value

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The complete value and the values I want to replace are not fixed, they can change, so I can't use the `SUBSTITUTE()` function alone

The values I have in my `Column A` have this template:

```
https://int.testpage.com/national/france/ligue-2/@@@@/regular-season/r6326442/
https://int.testpage.com/international/world/olympics/2020-tokyo/s172221/final-stages/
https://int.testpage.com/national/denmark/1st-division/@@@@/regular-season/s63932424/
https://int.testpage.com/international/world/olympics/2020-tokyo/g1722251/quarters-stages/
```

I would like to replace this type of value with specific dollar signs:

```
r6326442 -> $$$$$
s172221 -> $$$$$
s63932424 -> $$$$$
g1722251 -> $$$$$
```

The result for the values I put as an example would be these:

```
https://int.testpage.com/national/france/ligue-2/@@@@/regular-season/$$$$$/
https://int.testpage.com/international/world/olympics/2020-tokyo/$$$$$/final-stages/
https://int.testpage.com/national/denmark/1st-division/@@@@/regular-season/$$$$$/
https://int.testpage.com/international/world/olympics/2020-tokyo/$$$$$/quarters-stages/
```

If the values were fixed, I could use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A,"r6326442","$$$$$"),"s172221","$$$$$"),"s63932424","$$$$$"),"g1722251","$$$$$"))
```

And add more `SUBSTITUTE` as new values appear, but I need to automate this because there are many values and they change always.

Is there any way to do this?

**Note:** The value always starts with a single letter at the beginning and followed only by random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "[a-z]\d+", "$$$$$"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I would like one more detail...... For example, if a value is ```/k2league-final/``` it also changes to ```/&&&&&league-final/```, is there any way to specify to change only if there is 1 letter and the rest just numbers up to the next bar?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, actually this becomes a problem, because these values should not be changed, only those with a one letter and the rest numbers up to the next ```/```. If you want, I can create a new question explaining it in detail!

Comment: @BrondbyIF try: `=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "([a-z]\d{5,10})", "$$$$$"))`